# Crystal build fails with error - cannot find -levent

Tags: crystal-lang

I was getting this error while trying to run a simple crystal program in my ubuntu.

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -levent (this usually means you need to install the development package for libevent)
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Error: execution of command failed with code: 1: `cc "${@}" -o /home/xyz/.cache/crystal/crystal-run-test.tmp  -rdynamic -L/home/xyz/.asdf/installs/crystal/1.1.1/bin/../lib/crystal/lib -lpcre -lm -lgc -lpthread -levent -lrt -ldl`

Answer (score 2):

Issue has been solved by installing `libevent` packages by running the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install libevent-dev
```